# Conditional retrieval of data through linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
            var Getdetails = (from p in XYZDb.tblPulls
                          join
                          ro in XYZDb.tblRentalOrders
                          on p.AffCode equals ro.AffCode.Value
                          join
                          tpsb in XYZDb.tblPullSheetBatchProcessings
                          on p.PullNo.ToString() equals tpsb.PullSheet

                          select new
                          {
                              PullNos = p.PullNo,
                              AffCode = p.AffCode,
                              TotalItems = p.TotalItems,
                              p.PostedOn,
                              p.UpdatedOn,
                              p.IsPrinted,
                              BatchName =  tpsb.BatchName 

                          })

                              .Where(i => i.PostedOn >= from_date && i.PostedOn <= to && i.IsPrinted != null).Distinct();
```

In the above code only the pullno having BatchName are coming, i want to retrieve all the pullno within that timezone, and if it is batched, then the BatchName will also appear. I am stuck on that. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left outer join,

```
 var Getdetails = (from p in XYZDb.tblPulls
                      join
                      ro in XYZDb.tblRentalOrders
                      on p.AffCode equals ro.AffCode.Value
                      join
                      tpsb in XYZDb.tblPullSheetBatchProcessings
                      on p.PullNo.ToString() equals tpsb.PullSheet into pt
                      from batch in pt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                      {
                          PullNos = p.PullNo,
                          AffCode = p.AffCode,
                          TotalItems = p.TotalItems,
                          p.PostedOn,
                          p.UpdatedOn,
                          p.IsPrinted,
                          BatchName = (batch == null ? String.Empty : batch.BatchName ) 

                      })
                      .Where(i => i.PostedOn >= from_date && i.PostedOn <= to && i.IsPrinted != null).Distinct();
```